# Javascript canvas simple lightsource

Tags: javascript, canvas, radial-gradients

I'm making a game with javascript canvas. I'm drawing all the game elements, like the player, blocks and lines, but I don't want you to see all that. Instead want the whole screen to be black, expect for in some places where there is lightsources. I don't need any shadows, just a circle on the screen that is lit up with a radial gradient. I am able to achieve this for one lightsource by adding a transparent gradient after I have drawn everything else, like this: (imagine the red rectangle to be all the things in the game)

```
//Drawing all the game elements 
ctx.fillStyle = "red"; 
ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 400, 300);

//adding the darkness and the lightsources
var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(150, 100, 5, 150, 100, 100);
grd.addColorStop(0, "transparent");
grd.addColorStop(1, "black");
ctx.fillStyle = grd; ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 400);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vmrynmx/2/)

But how can I achieve this with multiple lightsources? The technique showed won't work.

I have tried using the Illuminated.js api, but that was incredibly slow, and I don't need anything of the shadows and all that fancy stuff, just a circle where you can see the game.

Comment: I'm not experienced with canvas, but in theory: Draw the lights as *white->transparent* gradients on black background, in a separate context (buffer, image, canvas?), and then paint this onto your scene with multiply blend mode.

Comment: That might work, I will look into it.

Comment: You might want to check http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/, they might have something for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of my approach - create black&white mask and multiply the base with it:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

//Drawing all the game elements 
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 400, 300);

//adding the darkness and the lightsources
function addlight(ctx, x, y) {
  var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(x, y, 10, x, y, 150);
  grd.addColorStop(0, "white");
  grd.addColorStop(1, "transparent");
  ctx.fillStyle = grd;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 400);
}

var buffer = document.createElement('canvas');
buffer.width = 600;
buffer.height = 400;
b_ctx = buffer.getContext('2d');
b_ctx.fillStyle = "black";
b_ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 400);
addlight(b_ctx, 150, 100);
addlight(b_ctx, 350, 200);
addlight(b_ctx, 450, 250);

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
ctx.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="400" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
```